# Python large text file searching

Tags: python, search, text

I have a 500 MB text file that was made a long time ago. It has what looks like html or xml tags but they are not consistent throughout the file. I am trying to find the information between two tags that do not match. What I am using currently works but is very slow: myDict has a list of keywords in it. I can only guarantee the X+key and /N exist. There are no other tags that are consistent. The Dictionary has 18000 keys.

```
for key in myDict:
    start_position = 0

    start_position = the_whole_file.find('<X>'+key, start_position)

    end_position = the_whole_file.find('</N>', start_position)

    date =  the_whole_file[start_position:end_position]
```

Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: hmmm what? so you are looking for `<x>some_key some_data_you_might_want_if_key_in_dict</n>`? 500MB is not that huge ...

Answer (score 2):

reverse the way you are doing it, instead of iterating through the dictionary and searching for potential matches.  iterate through potential matches and search the dictionary

```
import re
for part in re.findall("\<X\>(.*)\<\/N\>",the_whole_text):
    key = part.split(" ",1)[0]
    if key in my_dict:
       do_something(part)
```

since dictionary lookup is `O(1)` as opposed to string finding of `O(N)` (searching the whole file for every key is expensive ...)

so searching your file contents is `~O(500,000,000)` and you are doing that 18,000 times

this way you only search the file once finding all potentials ... then you look up each one to see if its in your data dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can always read the file line by line instead of storing the whole file in memory:

```
inside_tag = False
data = ''
with open(your file, 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        if '</N>' in line:
            data += line.split('<X>')[0]
            print data
            inside_tag = False
        if inside_tag:
            data += line
        if '<X>' in line:
            data = line.split('<X>')[-1]
            inside_tag = True
```

Note that this does not work when the beginning and end tags are on the same line.

Comment: that is almost certainly not an issue ... 500MB is not much ram

Comment: fair enough ... it's not a great answer anyway :-)